# Aluminum sheet as an underlay for electonic equipment

Tags: rf, ground, safety, grounding

I am planning to build a NAS into a (sufficiently ventilated) closet. For flame protection and heat spreading, I mean to put a 2x700x550mm aluminum sheet under the equipment. Is this a good idea?

Specifically:

Should I ground the plate?

If I ground the plate using the earthing conductor of the same power outlet I use for the NAS, will this influence the signal quality of the Power LAN that I mean to use as a network connection for the NAS?

Will an aluminum basis wreak havoc on wifi reception, which I mean to use as a backup connection? 3 sides of the closet are brick wall/plaster, the front is wood. The router is maybe 5m away in the next room.

For wifi connectivity, does it make a difference if I ground the aluminum sheet or not?

Comment: Err, why do you expect the NAS to catch fire? Or perhaps I'm misunderstanding...

Comment: @uint128_t I'm an aerospace engineer. I expect everything to catch fire ;). Seriously, I don't think it will, but I would rather be on the safe side, with unattended electronics and plenty of flamables in the same closet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think a plate is going to help very much for any of the things you are trying to do. If you actually need to prevent spread of flames, you would probably want to put metal under, and up the walls all around the NAS. But that would adversely affect wifi. If you do it anyway, I would not bother grounding the aluminum.

I don't see how putting aluminum plate or sheet under and appliance will help keep it cool. Especially in an adequately ventilated closet.

There are other materials besides metal for fire resistance such as gypsum board (which provides some limited resistance) and some rockwool materials with excellent fire resistance and insulation properties.

If you really need fire protection, I recommend using fire rated insulation. Roxul is one brand. If you use aluminum anyway, I suggest you put the aluminum between your NAS and the insulation. And I suggest you make sure there is a continuous insulation barrier between your NAS and any combustible material such as wood.

Note: I am not saying fire protection is required around an NAS. That is your premise. I am assuming it is true for the purposes of this answer. In reality, I am not sure you really need to put fire protection around an NAS. But if you do, you might as well do it right.

Comment: I think I will go with the gypsum board. It's just that the current shelf on which the stuff rests is a press board that looks like it's just begging for a spark. Makes me queasy put electronics on it that run all day and night.

Comment: two layers of plasterboard is considered to be fire resistant for 30 minutes from the perspective of building regulations.

Answer (score 1):

A plate of metal (or anything conductive) will affect your antenna pattern, and it will do it whether grounded or not (although in subtly different ways).  It's unlikely to prevent a connection unless it's directly between the communicating nodes, or within one wavelength of either one, although you might see some signal degradation (or improvement -- interference patterns can be become very complex, depending on frequency and what other conductors and absorbers are already in the area).

If your WiFi interface has an typical jointed external antenna, you'll almost certainly be able to position it for a good connection.  Worst case, you can use a coax cable to place the antenna farther from the NAS.

If you're going to ground the plate, do so before tuning antenna placement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if the material that would work best for you is a ceramic tray. I tend to repurpose things, so I'd be looking through a medical supply catalog for this. 
I'm with you on the gypsum. Material, glue and finish materials-who knows what substances you're working with.